# UnitTest Mobile Service TableController

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I am currently trying to write unit tests for a mobile service .net backend.

I already created a mocked database context using Effort.

But I dont really know how to initialize a table controller to test it.

I tried this little unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private MobileServiceContext _context = null;
    private GroupController _controller = null;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
        _context = new MobileServiceContext(connection);

        _controller = new GroupController(_context);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetAll()
    {
        var result = _controller.GetAccessibleGroups();
    }
}
```

The GetAccessibleGroups Method is still in its default state:

```
public class GroupController : TableController<Group>
{
//...
    public IQueryable<Group> GetAccessibleGroups()
    {
        return Query();
    }
```

But it fails in the Get Method with NullReferenceException when calling Query();

How can I initialize the controller so i dont get a NullReferenceException?

Comment: Can you post the code of `_controller.GetAccessibleGroups();`?

Comment: Of course, i added it to the question. But its still in the default state.

Comment: A .NET mobile service is just a customized Web API, so you should be able to use testing techniques like these: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: even i am getting same  error, when i am trying to test my controller which extends this table controller

Answer (score 0):

Man, this is an old answer but this should solve your problem!!!
I had just developed a generic solution to unit testing TableControllers.

firstable you gotta handle the setting and this can only be done by initializing the tablecontroller by DomainManager.

You could add at your controller the following method:

```
    public void SetDomainManager(EntityDomainManager<TModel> domainManager)
    {
        DomainManager = domainManager;
    }
```

then at your code

```
public class UnitTest1
{
private MobileServiceContext _context = null;
private GroupController _controller = null;

[TestInitialize]
public void SetupTest()
{
    DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
    _context = new MobileServiceContext(connection);
    _controller = new GroupController();
    _controller.SetDomainManager(new EntityDomainManager<Group>(_context, _controller.Request));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGetAll()
{
    var result = _controller.GetAccessibleGroups();
}
```

}

I believe that using this code, you should be able to Unit Test your TableController. also watch my generic solution its cleaner and can be apply to any controller. I'll leave you the link of my solution: [TableControllers Unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728417/tablecontrollers-unit-test)