# TableControllers Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure

So I'm trying to write a simple tablecontroller Unit test for my backend??

I havent been able to do so, all I've achieve is writing unit testing for ApiControllers but is there a way to write a Unit test for TableControllers?

What I'll like to do is this:

```
public class AuctionController : TableController<Auction>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Auction>(context, Request);
    }

    // GET tables/Auction
    public IQueryable<Auction> GetAllAuction()
    {
        return Query(); 
    }

    // GET tables/Auction/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<Auction> GetAuction(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/Auction/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<Auction> PatchAuction(string id, Delta<Auction> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/Auction
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuction(Auction item)
    {
        Auction current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/Auction/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteAuction(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

and i wish to make a test controller like this one:

```
[TestClass]
public class AuctionControllerTests
{
    private readonly AuctionController _controller;

    public AuctionControllerTests()
    {
        _controller = new AuctionController();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Fetch_all_existing_items()
    {
        Assert.Equal(2, _controller.GetAllTodoItems().ToList().Count);
    }
}
```

how can I possibly be able to get this to work??? Please I would appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Thanks for the mocking solution, It worked but I wrote a generic better solution without using mocking framework, I'll apply mocking framework later, right now I'll stick with fakes and real dbs for integration tests.

but firstable I wrote a Generic TableController in order to apply multiple EntityData and DbContext for those who had more than one Context, also you could apply a FakeContext thanks to the abstraction of interfaces but i havent applied to this example.

First This is my BaseController:

```
//This is an abstract class so we can apply inheritance to scalfolded tablecontrollers<T>.
public abstract class BaseController<TModel, TDbContext> : TableController<TModel> where TModel : class, ITableData
                                                                                       where TDbContext:DbContext, new()
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        var context = new TDbContext();
        SetDomainManager(new EntityDomainManager<TModel>(context, Request));
    }

    public void SetDomainManager(EntityDomainManager<TModel> domainManager)
    {
        DomainManager = domainManager;
    }
}
```

this is my scalfolded controller with my basecontroller applied!!!

```
public class AuctionController : BaseController<Auction, MobileServiceContext>    
{        
    public IQueryable<Auction> GetAllAuction()
    {
        return Query(); 
    }

    // GET tables/Auction/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<Auction> GetAuction(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/Auction/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<Auction> PatchAuction(string id, Delta<Auction> patch)
    {
         return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/Auction
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuction(Auction item)
    {
        Auction current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/Auction/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteAuction(string id)
    {
         return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

With my generic application I can apply any DbContext that way you could even apply FakeDbContexts in order to avoid SqlConnection or Cloud connection such as Azure which is the one I used in this example.

**UPDATED MARCH 14th, 2018**

All this two library are on my Backend project, now I'll show you my test project in order to Unit Test a TableController

```
 public abstract class ControllerTestBase<TController, TModel, TDbContext> where TController : BaseController<TModel, TDbContext>, new() 
                                                                           where TModel : class, ITableData
                                                                           where TDbContext: DbContext, new()
{
    protected readonly TController Controller;

    protected ControllerTestBase()
    {   
        Controller = new TController();
        Controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        Controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var context = new TDbContext();        
        Controller.SetDomainManager(new EntityDomainManager<TModel>(context, Controller.Request));
    }
}
```

Ok thanks to this abstract class you can supress the initialize setup from the testing library because each time you run a test it will call the generic test constructor, setting up all the necessary requierements and thus avoid ArgumentNullExceptions and InvalidOperationExceptions such common problem for unit testing tablecontroller since isnt quite intuitive to initialize as an ApiController.

Finally if you modify this then you can run a test like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class AuctionControllerTest : ControllerTestBase<AuctionController, Auction, MobileServiceContext>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Fetch_All_Existing_Items()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, Controller.GetAllAuction().ToList().Count);
    }
}
```

thanks to my generic application you can now use this code as an example to be apply to your TableControllers and also if you follow the Interface Segregation Principle you could apply FakeDbContext to your Controllers.

For those who helped me thanks you opened my mind into coming with this solution!!!

Comment: Enrique, this looks like the closest and most elegant solution for testing TableControllers.  Unfortunately, after trying it I get "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: request" for any of the tests I try.   I have the code identical to yours... including the HttpRequestMessage parameter for the SetDomainManager call.   I wonder if you have any guesses/suggestions about what might be going on.  I just double checked and the Controller's Request property is null when the error is thrown.

Comment: I just updated, my ControllerTestBase, that version should be enough for you to avoid those exceptions.
Also you could use XUnit for controller testing its easier. but since you are using MSTest this updated version should be enough!!, Hope it helps, I havent test it yet, since It was an old answer!! let me know please!!

Comment: Really nice of you.  I'll go try it out now.

Comment: Hey buddy, did it work?? if it work, I would appreciate to favor me, with a positive vote!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. it is possible but you code is not unit testable. Here are the steps for you

1. Find a way inject your depedencies MobileServiceContext and DomainManager
2. You need to set up contexts and requests etc as in shown in the following code.

(Code assumes you are using Moq)

```
public class ControllerUnitTestBase<T> where T: Controller      
{
    private Action<RouteCollection> _routeRegistrar;
    private Mock<HttpRequestBase> _mockRequest;

    protected virtual Action<RouteCollection> RouteRegistrar
    {
        get { return _routeRegistrar ?? DefaultRouteRegistrar; }
        set { _routeRegistrar = value; }
    }

    protected Mock<HttpRequestBase> MockRequest
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mockRequest == null)
            {
                _mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            }

            return _mockRequest;
        }
    }

    public abstract T TargetController { get; }

    protected void TargetSetup()
    {
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteRegistrar(routes);

        var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        responseMock.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string url) => url);

        var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        contextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(MockRequest.Object);
        contextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(responseMock.Object);
        contextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Session).Returns(Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>().Object);

        TargetController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextMock.Object, new RouteData(), TargetController);
        TargetController.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(contextMock.Object, new RouteData()), routes);
    }

    protected void DefaultRouteRegistrar(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
 }
```

Inherit from this code and make sure you call TargetSetup() before test execution ( maybe in test initialization (setup). And you are good to go as in:

```
  [TestClass] 
  public class AuctionControllerTests: TestControllerBase<AuctionController> 
  {

    public AuctionController TargetController { 
      get {return new AuctionController();//inject your mocked dependencies}}

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        TargetSetup()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry pal but your code has errors and to be honest I dont know how to solve them.

'UrlHelper' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments,
The name 'Target' does not exist in the current context,
The name 'UrlParameter' does not exist in the current context

what i was looking for its to make an integration test, I dont want it to mock results!!!

Comment: Yeah. I fixed the Target. But the UrlHelper and UrlParameter add the namespaces using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing; You need to reference the mvc/ web assemblies in your test project

Comment: Thanks man!!! it worked and also gave me an idea of how to develop my own generic version since i was able to understand the underhood of a tablecontrollers or apicontroller.

Comment: Well my generic version its an answer to my own post. Try it, it works fine man! I ve been creating a tested backend thanks to unit test.